# How to match Javascript unicode string precessing with php?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, character-encoding, char

I am trying to handle strings on both php and javascript and I want them to behave the same. I wrote a javascript version of php chr() fucntion to implement this. However I run into some uft-8 unicode issue. For example, I want to create a string with Chinese characters "a大小b" which I can do correctly in php but fail in javascipt using the codes below. I want to ask experts what is wrong with the implementation.

Output are:

```
  php str=a----
  php str=a�----
  php str=a��----
  php str=a大----
  php str=a大�----
  php str=a大��----
  php str=a大小----
  php str=a大小b----

  --------

  js str=a---
  js str=aå---
  js str=aå¤---
  js str=aå¤§---
  js str=aå¤§å---
  js str=aå¤§å°---
  js str=aå¤§å°---
  js str=aå¤§å°b---
```

The codes I used are as the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<?php 
    $string5 = "" ; 
    $str_a = chr(97) ; 
    $string5 .= $str_a ;   echo "php str=$string5----<br>" ; 


    $str_c1 = chr(229) ; 
    $string5 .= $str_c1 ;   echo "php str=$string5----<br>" ; 
    $str_c2 = chr(164) ; 
    $string5 .= $str_c2 ;   echo "php str=$string5----<br>" ; 
    $str_c3 = chr(167) ; 
    $string5 .= $str_c3 ;   echo "php str=$string5----<br>" ; 


    $str_cs1 = chr(229) ; 
    $string5 .= $str_cs1 ;   echo "php str=$string5----<br>" ; 
    $str_cs2 = chr(176) ; 
    $string5 .= $str_cs2 ;   echo "php str=$string5----<br>" ; 
    $str_cs3 = chr(143) ; 
    $string5 .= $str_cs3 ;   echo "php str=$string5----<br>" ; 


    $str_b= chr(98) ; 
    $string5 .= $str_b ;   echo "php str=$string5----<br>" ; 

    echo "<br><br>--------<br><br>" ; 
?>


<script language = "JavaScript">   

    function chr2(codePt) {
      if (codePt > 0xFFFF) { 
        codePt -= 0x10000;
        return String.fromCharCode(0xD800 + (codePt >> 10), 0xDC00 + (codePt & 0x3FF));
      }
      return String.fromCharCode(codePt);
    }

    var string5 = "" ; 
    var str_a = chr2(97) ; 
    string5 += str_a ;     document.write( "js str="+string5+"---<br>"  ); 

    var str_c1 = chr2(229) ; 
    string5 += str_c1 ;   document.write( "js str="+string5+"---<br>"  ); 
    var str_c2 = chr2(164) ; 
    string5 += str_c2 ;   document.write( "js str="+string5+"---<br>"  ); 
    var str_c3 = chr2(167) ; 
    string5 += str_c3 ;   document.write( "js str="+string5+"---<br>"  ); 


    var str_cs1 = chr2(229) ; 
    string5 += str_cs1 ;   document.write( "js str="+string5+"---<br>"  ); 
    var str_cs2 = chr2(176) ; 
    string5 += str_cs2 ;   document.write( "js str="+string5+"---<br>"  ); 
    var str_cs3 = chr2(143) ; 
    string5 += str_cs3 ;   document.write( "js str="+string5+"---<br>"  ); 

    var str_b = chr2(98) ; 
    string5 += str_b ;   document.write( "js str="+string5+"---<br>"  ); 

</script>


</div> 
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP and JavaScript strings are fundamentally different. A PHP string is a series of bytes. A JavaScript string is a series of characters. (Actually a series of UTF-16 code units, but that's irrelevant to this example.)

`大` is character U+5927 (Han Ideograph Big). To generate it in JavaScript you would use `String.fromCharCode(0x5927)` (or `chr2(0x5927)` using the above helper function).

229, 164, 167 is the byte representation of `大` using the UTF-8 encoding (`"\xE5\xA4\xA7"`). Splitting the character in the middle of the byte sequence is invalid which is why you get the `�` error in the output of PHP. You can't split the byte sequence in the middle in JavaScript as its string model is character-based, so the code will never work the same.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. For some reason, I have to split the string in Javascript and recover the uincode string back. How to modify the Javascript chr2() function or the js codes in order to make it work?

Comment: The JavaScript string *is* the Unicode string. It is the PHP string that is not Unicode but a series of bytes. JavaScript strings cannot hold individual bytes. If you want to get a mangled (mojibake) String where each `charCodeAt` represents a UTF-8 byte unit there is an idiomatic trick: `unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))`. But you rarely want to be touching bytes at the client side; the browser is a Unicode-focused environment.

Comment: I am new in these unicode and utf-8 issues. I cannot get the point of your hint to  use encodeURICompoent(s) to concatenate the splited unicode word. How to change the codes above using this concept and recover the "a大小b" string back in the above Javascipt codes. Thanks!